# How can I change value on one table while creating an instance on another in django model?

Tags: python, django

**I wanted to select multiple users from the `Profile` and change their `amountDue` to the amount on the `Matchpayment` model, in other words - the `amountdue` for each player should increment according to each of the `Matchpayment` they are in using the amount from `MatchPayment`. Hope it makes sense.**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amountDue = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class MatchPayment(models.Model):
    match = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Profile)
    datespent = models.DateField('Date Spent')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.match
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough. If you can, please restructure the question.

Comment: A single MatchPayment model instance belongs to multiple players. Hence, amount belongs to multiple players.